# Login authenticated endpoints through an api

Tags: swift, api, authentication, vapor

I'm writing a web frontend in vapor which has a login and signup pages, and an authenticated user area with actions that require being logged in.

There is a seperate instance (also swift vapor) which handles authentication over a rest api (basically there are multiple other things which can authenticate, and from various sources/reasons so made sense to have it as a seperate instance).

The idea is all the authentication is passed on from the webserver to the api

The idea and what I have currently is the web's `/login` page has a form which sends a `/login` POST request which talks via the api instance sending a post request (`/auth/login`). This either succeeds or not. and the webserver responds based on the api response

The issue I have is how I persist that authentication- do I need some custom middleware to store the session token or check the token via the api that I can use on subsequent requests?

I've enabled bearer authentication on the api, and the api's success login reply json object returns the session token that I check in the bearer authorisation.

There's also a `vapor-session` set cookie returned in the api's login response. I've tried adding that into the web's login response (redirect response to the logged in area) so the browser should send back the session cookie on future requests but I haven't as of yet been able to get this to work. The browser is sending a different value for vapor-session cookie.

Does this sound like a sensible approach?

I'm not sure the best way of going about this

Including some bits of code to help see what I have so far

API instance's routes, I'm sure if I need the session authenticator or not

```
auth//.grouped(UserDB.sessionAuthenticator())
    .grouped(UserAuthenticator())
    .grouped(UserDB.guardMiddleware())
    .group("")
        { authenticated in
            authenticated.get("me", use: getCurrentUser)
```

This is the `UserAuthenticator` that supports bearer authentication by looking up the session token in the db. Could I just use the session token in bearer auth header for all requests web -> api? I'm not sure how I'd provide that on each web request- should I be setting a cookie? Is that basically what the vapor-session cookie is?

```
struct UserAuthenticator: BearerAuthenticator {
    
    typealias User = UserDB

    func authenticate(bearer: BearerAuthorization, for request: Request) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
        
        let tokenHash = SHA256.hash(bearer.token)
        
        return request.sessionTokens
            .find(tokenHash: tokenHash)
            .flatMap {
                if let sessionToken = $0 {
                    request.auth.login(sessionToken.user)
                }
                return request.eventLoop.makeSucceededVoidFuture()
            }
        
   }
    
}
```

I haven't put any middleware on the authenticated web routes- should I be doing that and checking there? would I do an api request in the middleware `authenticate` method?

I'm not really sure what the correct approach is here

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your front-end and API are separate you need a custom `User` type to add to the authenticated session - this is how you know a user is logged in. You probably don't need to store much on the user, just their username and the API token